# Как узнать просмотрено ли сообщение или нет (C#, MailKit, MimeKit)?

Tags: c#, mailkit

Как узнать просмотрено ли сообщение или нет с помощью библиотеки MailKit.

```
mimeMessages.ForEach(iMessage => 
            {
                dgvMessages.Rows.Add(new object[] { iMessage.From, iMessage.Subject, /* Сюда нужно добавить из iMessage инфу о том просмотрено ли сообщение или нет */ });
                Console.WriteLine(iMessage.Subject);
            });
```

Comment: Хм, а вы [документацию](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Introduction.htm) читали?

Comment: English low skill (((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Результат.

```
   folder.Search(SearchQuery.All).ToList().ForEach(uid =>
                {
                    MimeMessage mimeMessage = folder.GetMessage(uid);
                    dgvMessages.Rows.Add(new object[] { mimeMessage.From, mimeMessage.Subject, folder.Search(SearchQuery.NotSeen).Contains(uid) ? "Новое" : "Прочитано" });
                });
```

*Можно ли реализовать по другому?*